# set session on the click of edit button in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to set session on the click of edit button, before or on the page load in grocery crud.

```
 $crud->callback_before_update(array($this,'encrypt_password_callback'));
```

we are having this for call a method but it only works when i click update button,
my requirement is to call a method when the edit page loads.

Comment: Could you provide us with a little bit more info about your issue? And why you need to achieve this?

Comment: i am using session to use a value on the other pages using the same id, but session is setting on call of **callback_after_update**. but problem is, if user clicks on the other tabs at that point session is not set and getting error.

Comment: How are you checking if a session is set and where do you set it? Can you provide us with a bit more code so we can fully understand your problem?

Comment: what i want is, whenever i click the edit button from the grocery crud, a value should be set in a session variable or want to make call this function of controller, `code` function log_user_after_insert($post_array,$primary_key)
 {
  $this->session->set_userdata('event_id',$primary_key);
  return true;
 } `code`

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to simulate button click, here is simple example

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();">Check the box to simulate a button click
<br>
<input type="button" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button" onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');">
```

Or you can use jQuery

```
jQuery('#mydiv').click();
```

To make it work on links, I think you need to add an onclick handler and then redirect the page.